# What should be the format string to print "0x0" with swprintf()?

Tags: c++

I tried with `swprintf(buff, 4, L"%#03x", value)`, but when `value = 0`, I get `000` instead of `0x0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `L"0x%x", value`. Making the buffer have only four elements is probably a bad idea (as soon as `value` is greater than `0xF`). You should store the return value and make sure the string didn't get truncated:

```
int n = swprintf(buff, sizeof buff, L"0x%x", value);

if (n >= sizeof buff) { /* truncation! */ }
```

Comment: That's assuming that `buff` is an array -- if it's a pointer, you can't use `sizeof`.

Answer (score 4):

You need the "0x" in a literal, like "0x%03x".  The `x` format just prints the digits in hex, it doesn't add the 0x decoration.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8aky45ct.aspx says that flag `#` when used with the o, x, or X format, the # flag prefixes any nonzero output value with 0, 0x, or 0X, respectively.

Comment: The magic there is "any nonzero output value".  he asked specifically about 0.

Comment: value is any number with 1 hexadecimal digit. But when value is 0 I don't get the desired result.

Comment: I agree with your comment above. But I wonder if there isn't a solution for the case whether value is 0 or not ?